# Why does array variable outside of function cause issues for my JavaScript list app?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, push

The following JavaScript list app allows the user to input items at the click of a button into an array with the JS push method. DOM methods are then used to append the items to an unordered list. Example #1 includes the array variable WITHIN the function and properly appends a single item to a single list element. However, when placing the array variable BEFORE the function in example #2, a scenario occurs where the first item appends properly, but clicking again to add a second item results in the appending of both the new item AND the previous item (repeated) to a new list element. Why does the previous item get re-appended to the new list element when the array variable is included BEFORE the function? See examples below. Feedback is appreciated!

Example #1 JS:

```
<script>
  function add(){
    var array = [];
    var task = document.getElementById("task").value;
    array.push(task);

    var text = document.createTextNode(array);
    var elem = document.createElement("li");
    elem.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("myUl").appendChild(elem);
  };
</script>
```

Example #1 HTML:

```
<input id="task">
<button onclick="add()">add</button>
<ul id="myUl"></ul>
```

Example #2 JS:

```
<script>
var array = [];

  function add(){
    var array = [];
    var task = document.getElementById("task").value;
    array.push(task);

    var text = document.createTextNode(array);
    var elem = document.createElement("li");
    elem.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("myUl").appendChild(elem);
  };
</script>
```

Example #2 HTML:

```
<input id="task">
<button onclick="add()">add</button>
<ul id="myUl"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example 2 does exactly same as your example 1.

But probably, you do not intend to declare array variable inside the function in the second example. In that case, the array outside function is actually holding the list of all the tasks the user inputs.

Moreover, createTextNode takes a string, not an array as the argument. when you pass an array, it is converting array of tasks to comma-seperated string and appending to the list.

so, in your add() function, pass only the last added item to the createTextNode method, like

```
document.createTextNode(array[array.length - 1])
```

coming to your first example, it does not hold the inputs in your memory, as array variable is declared inside a function, and is initialised as an empty array - every time the function is being called i.e when ever a task is added.

Comment: In the latter part of your answer, are you suggesting that it is better to have the array variable OUTSIDE of the function in order to avoid re-initializing the array everytime the function is called?

Comment: By the way, removing the duplicated array variable within the function and adding array.length - 1 as a text node worked. Appreciated!

Comment: Thank you. It is better to have the array variable outside the function, so that it holds as a data store for the application. You may later want to post it to a server, or use it in other part of the app. This ensures the separation of model(data) from view(user interface).

Answer (score 0):

In example 2, you have a duplicty in `array` variable. What you probably need is this:

```js
var array = [];

function add() {
  var task = document.getElementById("task").value;
  array.push(task);

  var text = document.createTextNode(task);
  var elem = document.createElement("li");
  elem.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("myUl").appendChild(elem);
  
  console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="task">
  <button onclick="add()">add</button>
  <ul id="myUl"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, I doubt that you can create a text node from an array (and that you *want that*). I think that what you ment is `task`variable.

Comment: Removing the duplicated array variable within the function and adding task as a text node worked. Appreciated!